# How to interpret odds ratio

Tags: regression, logistic, interpretation, logit, odds-ratio

I have the following data set and I applied logistic regression and my model is given below.

[image]

$logit(\pi_i) = -60.71 + 34.27*Dose_i$

I know that $e^{34.27}$ gives the odds ratio, but don't know how to interpret this. Thoughts please

Comment: If you find the answers to the duplicate insufficiently clear or thorough, then please [search our site](http://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=odds+ratio+interpret) for additional threads on this topic.

Comment: The links provided by @whuber will help. But just to add a short notes, your x is in common log scale and if you interpret it as 1 unit increase you're making the chemical 10 times more concentrated. Substitute something smaller like 10% (a 0.0953 unit increase in log scale) to avoid getting an astronomical odds ratio, currently it is about 764000000000000 if you analyze it straight up with 1 unit increase in the variable Dose.